# Можно ли внести изменения в карту Яндекса после её загрузки?

Tags: javascript, яндекс-карты

У меня возникла такая ***ситуация***: при загрузке страницы загружается карта с неким количеством плейсмарков, и я хочу по клику пользователя на специальную кнопку (на странице, но не на карте) отобразить ещё несколько плейсмарков.

***Код*** (если надо):

```
function ymapsShow(markType) {
  if (markType == true) {
    var myMap = new ymaps.Map('map', {
      center: [59.930480, 30.327198],
      zoom: 8,
      controls: []
    }),
    // Самая обычная синяя метка
    myPlacemark = new ymaps.Placemark([parseFloat(document.getElementById("x").innerHTML), parseFloat(document.getElementById("y").innerHTML)], 
      { 
        hintContent: 'Москва!', 
        balloonContent: 'Столица России' 
      });
    // Конец самой обычной метки
  } else {
    var myMap = new ymaps.Map('map', {
      center: [59.930480, 30.327198],
      zoom: 8,
      controls: []
    }),
    myPlacemark = new ymaps.Placemark(
      [parseFloat(document.getElementById("x").innerHTML), parseFloat(document.getElementById("y").innerHTML)], 
      {
        hintContent: 'Собственный значок метки',
        balloonContent: 'Это красивая метка'
      }, 
      {
        // Опции.
        // Необходимо указать данный тип макета.
        iconLayout: 'default#image',
        // Своё изображение иконки метки.
        iconImageHref: "<%= asset_path('icons/blocks_3.svg') %>",

        // Размеры метки.
        iconImageSize: [30, 30],
        // Смещение левого верхнего угла иконки относительно
        // её "ножки" (точки привязки).
        iconImageOffset: [-5, -30]
      });
  }
  myMap.geoObjects.add(myPlacemark);
};
```

***Вопрос*** состоит в том, можно ли это сделать на уже загруженной карте или обязательно нужно сначала её удалить и добавить новую уже вместе с новым набором плейсмарков?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы можете добавить метки на карту в любой момент времени, не создавая её заново

Comment: Спасибо! Могу я попросить Вас несколько расширить свой ответ, т.к. не могу найти способа для получения существующей карты в переменную. Есть только var myMap = new ymaps(), который создаёт каждый раз как раз-таки новую карту.

Comment: метки всегда добавляются после создания карты, например, вот тут: https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/placemark

Comment: Позволю себе не согласиться - в данном примере они добавляются вместе с созданием карты. Меня интересует, можно ли снова получить доступ к карте и её геоОбъектам, после того как документ(веб-страница) полностью загружен?

Comment: Это вам в учебник по javascript в тему про глобальные переменные)  конечно, можно, просто вам нужно создать переменную карты вне функции init и при добавлении меток проверять, что карта существует

Comment: Теперь получилось, спасибо!